# Magento Top Navigation - Add 'Shop All Styles' link of Level0 nav at end of Level1 items

Tags: magento, navigation

Is there a way to include a `'Shop all (parent category)'` link at the end of the nav level1 lis **without** doing it by adding another category called 'shop all ...'

Eg:

```
Tops:
     T-Shirts
     Tanks
     Jackets
     Shop All Tops <- Dynamically add this which links to the Tops parent category.
```

The top.phtml only contains

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Adding a `<li>` after echo $_menu adds it to the end the level0. The renderCategoriesMenuHtml function is in a Navigation.php file that is just all functions.

Basically I want to find the parent category, store it in a variable and echo it (and the link) at the end of the level1 list items but don't know if there is a .phtml file to allow me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is very little you can do with the default template to customize the nav menu. Your best bet would be to rewrite the template to suit your needs, ditching:

```
 $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml()
```

And instead, running some foreach loops on each category level.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks.

Comment: You could always build a new module that rewrites that generic method with one that provides some flexibility. Also, on the bright side, it's a little bit satisfying rewriting that template and building your nav menu sans javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I added my solution as an answer to this question. I'm not confident on modules so I just edited the top.phtml.

Comment: Google silk software module creator. While some of the generated code is questionable, it typically gives you a solid starting point to figuring things out yourself. And yeah, the template you posted is pretty much how you have to do it. If you have to go several levels deep in the nav, the getModel() stipulation gets annoying, so something to consider if its worth the time to just build your own model.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I was after by replacing all content in top.phtml with the following. It keeps the same classes for level0 and level1 and the structure of spans inside anchor tags so that any previous styling would be kept.

```
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
<div class="nav-container">   
 <ul id="nav">
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li class="level0 level-top first parent">
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                   </span> <?php echo $_category->getName() ?></span>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li class="level1">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                   <span><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><span>Shop all <?php echo $_category->getName() ?></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```